# If the $(n-1)$th moment exists does the $n$th moment necessarily exist?

Tags: moments

Let's suppose the distribution is unknown but that the second moment is known to be finite. Doesn't this imply that the distribution should fall off exponentially fast and therefore higher moments must also exist?

Comment: No. Simple counterexample: t distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: Also [asked](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333571/15941) on math.SE where the OP has already accepted an answer.

Comment: Why would the existence of variance imply that the distribution (by which I assume you actually mean density or pmf) falls off exponentially?  (*Edit: removed parts no longer needed in comment*)

Comment: This isn't a question for a class as school has ended. It's just a question that occurred to me. I didn't know that you couldn't ask a question on multiple SE sites...

Comment: It's a good question. Things actually work in the other direction: existence of the $n$th (absolute) moment implies existence of all moments less than $n$ (down to the first).

Comment: @Glen_b My intuition was that if the continuous function fell off in a polynomial manner then the the dominant term in the integral(for variance) would be $ C x^{2−n}$ and the integral of this function from zero to infinity would be infinite. Hence I thought it had to be exponential. But, this was pretty silly to consider as a distribution can't be polynomial to begin with...otherwise the area under distribution would be infinite.

Comment: @HongOoi A slight expansion of your comment (at least stating explicitly which moments are finite for a $t_n$) would probably form a reasonable answer for this question, if you'd like to do that.